# Printing without opening print dialog in php

Tags: php

Hai Guys,
         I have to print a page in php but i dont want to use window.print ..... I have to print without opening the print dialog box... I am using php.....

Comment: what a question - again!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PHP is a server side language, and therefore it can only affect actions at the server. Printing is a client-side action and so PHP can't help you out. Javascript is what you're talking about with `window.print()` and as far as I know, that's the only programmatic way to print from the browser.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this in firefox. Just search for

```
user_pref("print.always_print_silent",true);
user_pref("print.show_print_progress",false);
```

I am also looking for a way to do it in opera....

Answer (score 1):

Pandiya,

The answer you looking for is: No, there is no existing solution that allows you to trigger print event without user input (via prompting print dialog).